# Android SQLite INSERT causes application crash

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, crash

I am trying to insert some data into a table I created. I have this class:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "db_mydatabase";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TBL_USERS = "users";
private static final String TBL_USERSE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                            + TBL_USERS + "(id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            + "usr varchar(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE, psw varchar(512));";

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

public List<String> GetUsersList() {
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, usr FROM " + TBL_USERS, null);
    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USR"));
                users.add(firstName);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return users;
}

public void CreateNewUser(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TBL_USERS + " (usr, psw) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "')");
            //If I comment this line, it doesn't crashes anymore, but I don't see why
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TBL_USERSE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_USERS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

So, when I press the REGISTER button, the username and password from a EditText are sent to CreateNewUser. My Activity class looks like this:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
List<String> values;
DataBase dtb;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    dtb = new DataBase(MainActivity.MainContext);
    values = dtb.GetUsersList();

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.MainContext, R.layout.listitem, values));

    Button Create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Create);
    Create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
           EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);
           if (username.getText().length()>0 && password.getText().length()>0) {
               if (values.indexOf(username.getText())<0) {
                   dtb.CreateNewUser(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                   values = dtb.GetUsersList();
               }
           }
       }
    });
}
```

}

I am a beginner as a SQLite programmer and I get this understandable critical error and crash

```
> **04-24 12:30:51.340: E/CursorWindow(7986): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 2** 04-24 12:30:51.350:
> D/AndroidRuntime(7986): Shutting down VM 04-24 12:30:51.350:
> W/dalvikvm(7986): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0x4001b188) 04-24 12:30:51.350: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):
> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
> **04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1
> failed** 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):  at
> android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> com.bma.myagenda.DataBase.GetUsersList(DataBase.java:32) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> com.bma.myagenda.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:46)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364) 04-24 12:30:51.380:
> E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179) 04-24 12:30:51.380:
> E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-24 12:30:51.380:
> E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-24 12:30:51.380:
> E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
> 04-24 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 04-24
> 12:30:51.380: E/AndroidRuntime(7986):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USR"));
```

To:

```
String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("usr"));  //USR != usr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your insert code with this:

```
public void CreateNewUser(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(usr, username);
initialValues.put(psw, password);

db.insert(TBL_USERS, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a better way of escaping the strings, I suppose

Comment: @ali yes, that will escape strings as well. And it returns you the id of the newly inserted column which execSQL can't.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USR"));
```

to

```
String firstName = c.getString(1);
```

the Error

```
CursorWindow(7986): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 2
...java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
```

means that you request the column with index -1 in in the first row of a `Cursor`. The only part of your code that requests data from a `Cursor` is `c.getString(columnIndex)`.  That means that the columnIndex you get there must be `-1`. Now if you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) of `Cursor.getColumnIndex` you see will find:

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.

Meaning there is no column named `"USR"`. If you look at your table definition you can see that you named it `"usr"`. So to fix your error you can do

```
String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("usr"));
```

But (that is optional and can lead to errors): Since you requested the `Cursor` as `SELECT id, usr FROM ..` you are guaranteed that `id` is column `0` and `usr` is column `1` in your `Cursor` and you can simply use the `1` directly.

There is also other things you could improve:

```
if (c != null ) {
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        String firstName = c.getString(1);
        users.add(firstName);
    }
    c.close();
}
```

*a)* you can simplify the `if () do {} while ()` to a simple `while() {}`
*b)* you should close the `Cursor` once you don't need it. You prevent at least a warning that way.

You should also make your `INSERT` save against errors / injection attacks by using the bindArgs version of `execSQL`. Try entering a `'` in a username and you will see that it will crash the way you do it. Using bindArgs will prevent that since it automatically escapes the `'`.

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TBL_USERS + " (usr, psw) VALUES (?, ?)", new String[]{ username, password });
```

> If I comment this line, it doesn't crashes anymore, but I don't see why

That is because the `Cursor` is empty then and you don't reach the code that caused the error.

One last thing: `varchar(128)` has no effect in SQLite since:

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values. [*source*](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)